# CSS grid: appearance of no grid-row-gap depending on content of adjacent cells

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
main {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-column-gap: 60px;
        grid-row-gap: 60px;
    }
    
    p {
       grid-column: 2 / span 1;
       margin-bottom: 0;
       background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    p + p {
      margin-top: -60px;
     }
```

```html
<main>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
    <p>Another paragraph of text</p>
    <p>Possibly another paragraph of text</p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
</main>
```

I have a simple two column grid, with headings in the left column and paragraph text in the right hand column. I also have grid-row-gap set to give a nice gap between the rows. This all works fine, until after a heading, there is more than one paragraph `<p>` element. This second `<p>` element goes into a new row. I want all the `<p>` paragraph text to be inside one cell. Or for there to be no grid-row-gap between rows containing adjacent `<p>` elements. Or some sort of fudge.

This is what I want. Two columns. `<h3>` in left column. Text in right column. And if there is more than one `<p>` for there to be no grid-row-gap (or the appearance of no gap) between them.

```
<h3> | <p>
==========
<h3> | <p>
==========
<h3> | <p>
     | <p>
     | <p>
=========
<h3> | <p>
```

Here is my code

```
<main>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
    <p>Another paragraph of text</p>
    <p>Possibly another paragraph of text</p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
</main> 

main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 60px;
    grid-row-gap: 60px;
}

p {
   grid-column: 2 / span 1;
   margin-bottom: 0;
  background-colour: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Is having a div not an option ?

Comment: No. The content is being provided by a CMS and I can't add divs easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the reasoning on the first child like below

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 60px;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  grid-column: 2;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
h3:not(:first-child),
h3:not(:first-child) + p{
  margin-top: 60px
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>

  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>

  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
  <p>Another paragraph of text</p>
  <p>Possibly another paragraph of text</p>

  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
</main>
```

Comment: That's great. I think this is better than my solution, as I prefer to use positive margins, than negative margin amounts (which I think can get confusing / messy).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can do something like this:

```
 p + p {
      margin-top: -60px;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most reasonable thing to do seems to be just wrapping your paragraphs in `div` elements.

```css
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 60px;
    grid-row-gap: 60px;
}

main div {
   grid-column: 2 / span 1;
} 

p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
    </div>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
      <p>Another paragraph of text</p>
      <p>Possibly another paragraph of text</p>
    </div>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Some text, blah, blah blah</p>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the content is being provided by a CMS and it is not easy for me to add divs